# What is the maximum number of subsets can be formed from n data subsets?

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the maximum number of subsets can be formed from $n$ data subsets of a fixed set by the operation of intersection, union, and complement?

---

I think the answer is $2^{2^n}$. Because $2^n$ -- the number of all subsets of a fixed set. Than $2^n$ will determine the number of all subsets of the data subsets. I am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking the number of subsets of the set of subsets (the power set) of a set of $n$ elements, the answer is $2^{2^n}$.  As you say, the power set of a set of $n$ elements has size $2^n$ and the size of the power set of that is $2^{2^n}$. This does not use the list of operations or the fact that they are "data subsets" (whatever that is),so I am not sure you are reading the question correctly.

What I think the question is asking is given a universal set (which might as well be $\Bbb N$) and $n$ (presumably disjoint) subsets (which might as well be $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\dots ,\{n\}$) How many subsets of $\Bbb N$ can you form from the given operations?

Comment: >>If you are asking the number of subsets of the set of subsets (the power set) of a set of n elements, the answer is $2^{2^n}$
Yes, that's what I'm asking! So, how can I prove it more strickly?

Comment: The above is fine.  Once you have that a set of $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets, just apply that to the set of $2^n$ elements